# Statistical test to measure significant difference between 4 binary classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, statistical-significance, binary-data

I have four versions of a neural network hardware. I am testing the hardwares to classify a single binary input into a binary output. The ANN hardwares are trained using a very simple relation, the NOT boolean function:
Input   Output
-1        1
1         -1

However, I am using the following relation for verification

Input..............Output

$>$zero............$<$zero

$<$zero............$>$zero

A perfect NOT function classifier would follow the relation above: Now, I want to compare the performance of the 4 ANN hardwares to the perfect classifier. What statistical test can I use to show the statistical significance between the ann hardware and the perfect classifier?

Comment: What's your performance measure? You need to decide if you're going to compare accuracy, AUC, F1, sensitivity, specificity, or something else entirely before you show that one algorithm performs better than another.

Comment: @NuclearWang   I am using the geometric mean of the sensitivity and specificity: https://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/congreso/kubat97addressing.pdf